# How to read a specific format ( XXX.X ) from UItextfield in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, textfield

I want to read a text from the text field in swift with XXX.X format.Suppose By XXX.X format I mean:

- 123.3 is valid
- 48.2 is valid
- 1.4 is valid
- 4 is valid
- 4.3.4 is invalid
- 5555.5 is invalid
- 123.34 is invalid

In other words, the text on the left side of the period must only have at most 3 characters and on the left side, must only have 1 character or no character at all if the user did not input "."

For now, my code works only for restriction of the number of "."

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let countdots = textField.text.components(separatedBy: ".").count)! - 1

    if countdots > 0 && string == "."
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be a floating point number? If so, what about locales that use a comma or other character instead of a period for the decimal separator?

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: @rmaddy yes it a float number. Indeed I can use a comma or another character for a separator but that is not my problem here. The problem here is how can I restrict the number of characters on the right side of "." (or another character as you mentioned) and the number of characters on the left side.

Comment: Replace    `return true` with  `countdots.first.count <= 3` and you done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func valid(_ s:String) -> Bool {
    func roundToPlaces(value:Double, places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return round(value * divisor) / divisor
    }
    if let num = Double(s) {
        if num >= 1000.0 {
            return false
        }
        if roundToPlaces(value:num, places:1) != num {
            return false
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Test on your input:

```
let test = [
    "123.3",
    "48.2",
    "1.4",
    "4",
    "4.3.4",
    "5555.5",
    "123.34"
]

for s in test {
    print(valid(s))
}
```

Result:

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
```

So that is your input and your desired output.

Comment: Fantastic! I've been solving this already for one whole day and you just solved it for me.thank you very much!

Comment: It does cover the specific examples you provided, but you might have to change it for other examples you didn't mention...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Regular Expression Might be wrong you need to fix it yourself)

```
-(BOOL)isValidValue:(NSString *)checkString{
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1}";
    NSPredicate *valueTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stricterFilterString];
    return [valueTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Test:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self isValidValue:@"123.3"] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

**[Update]**

for **Swift 3**:

```
func valueCheck(_ checkString: String) -> Bool {   
    var result = false
    do {
        let regex = try RegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1}", options: [])
        let results = regex.matches(in: checkString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, checkString.characters.count))
        if results.count > 0 {
            return true
        } else {
           return false
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: And this doesn't handle localization.